# Listing causes strange vertical spaces when put it on the next page

Tags: listings

I have simple document:

```
\subsubsection{Dodanie testu}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={ComplexTest},label={lst:complex-test}]
    public class ComplexTest{

        public testComplexAddition(){
            Complex a = new Complex(1,2);
            Complex b = new Complex(3,4);           
    }
\end{lstlisting}    
Some text   
\subsubsection{Uruchomienie testów}
Some text  
\subsubsection{Napisanie kodu}
Some text
```

with these settings for my listings:

```
\lstset{
language=Java,
captionpos=t,
tabsize=3,
frame=none,
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
stringstyle=\color{red},
numbers=left,
numbersep=-8pt,
showstringspaces=false,
basicstyle={\small\ttfamily}
}
```

my output looks like
for first page:
[image: First page]

for second page:

[image: Second page]

but when I put \pagebreak just before \begin{lstlisting} to have it on the next page I have got strange vertical spaces between subsubsections and texts. There is the output:

[image: Failure spaces]

PS. The same occours when I put additional lines of code to my listing and Latex implicit breaks line and put these lines on next page.

Comment: Use `\newpage` instead.

Comment: It dosen't work. Still the same problem.

Comment: What about `\clearpage`?

Comment: @Sigur it also dosen't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks for greeting. Best regards from Poland :)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek your answear is good enough! Close topic or something?

Comment: @mate: Since I would have answered the same, I have already voted for closing. Thus the question will then appear in the review queue and with four more votes it will be closed as duplicate.